# Binding details for Translation Manager using .NET API V2 Service from external source

Tags: web8.5, translation-manager, api

We are using SDL Web 8.5 where we've configured Translation Manager. We are building a solution to automate the Translation Manager process where we should be able to send items for translation from an external source.

Earlier we were able to do so by using

`Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.Api`

However with the new system I could find that we need to use the following two files for same:

```
Tridion.TranslationManager.V2.Data;
Tridion.TranslationManager.V2.TmService.Client
```

While trying to create a client for TmServiceClient as below:

```
 SessionAwareTmServiceClient _client = new SessionAwareTmServiceClient();
```

I am unable to find binding details on the CMS server? Can someone please help to provide the binding details for `SessionAwareTmServiceClient`.

Comment: I do not have a running tridion system with TM at the moment, so i will not write this as an answer as it is more a hint to find the settings than the actual solution. The tridion UI backend services communicate with the TM soap service. So somewhere in the tridion webroot folder structure you will find an endpoint definition named something with "tm" in a web.config folder. This can be copied to the config of your client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Binding for TM SOAP service looks like this

Binding is netTcpBinding:

```
<netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="TmNetTcpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
                <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
</netTcpBinding>
```

And endpoint:

```
<client>
    <endpoint name="TmBinaryEndpoint" address="net.tcp://localhost:2660/TranslationManager/V2/netTcp" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TmNetTcpBinding" contract="Tridion.TranslationManager.V2.TmService.Client.ISessionAwareTmService"/>
</client>
```

**Note that this is NetTCP ony there is no HTTP version.**

Comment: What is the location of this Configuration File?