# How to read information of Translation Job or connect Translation Manager by CoreService?

Tags: 2013-sp1, core-service, translation-manager

I am **working on Tridion 2013 SP1** version, I **want to read details like** number of Components in Translation Job and **number of successful/unsuccessful Components per language** or translation target.

I am trying to use CoreService but it seems CoreService doesn't read Translation Jobs directly, is there any translation plugin/translation service through which this information can be accessible?

Answer (score 7):

For Web 8 you have a dedicated service for this. It's configuration can be found in:
`\web\WebUI\WebRoot\Web.config`

Binding:

```
<binding name="TmNetTcpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
    <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
</binding>
```

Endpoint:

```
<endpoint name="TmBinaryEndpoint" address="net.tcp://localhost:2660/TranslationManager/V1/netTcp" 
binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TmNetTcpBinding" 
contract="Tridion.TranslationManager.V1.TmService.Client.ISessionAwareTmService"/>
```

In the **release notes for Web 8** it's stated:

- A new SOAP-based web service called the TmService is introduced; its
  primary use case is with Workflows

So this is not available prior to Web 8, 2013 sp1 does not have a dedicated service. I haven't tried working with Translation Jobs using "the regular" CoreService.

PS. Web 8.5 introduced **v2**:

Binding:

```
<binding name="TmNetTcpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
        <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
</binding>
```

Endpoint:

```
<endpoint name="TmBinaryEndpoint" address="net.tcp://localhost:2660/TranslationManager/V2/netTcp" 
binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TmNetTcpBinding" 
contract="Tridion.TranslationManager.V2.TmService.Client.ISessionAwareTmService"/>
```

You have related question here:

- [Binding details for Translation Manager using .NET API V2 Service from external source](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/18525/binding-details-for-translation-manager-using-net-api-v2-service-from-external)
- [Translation Manager using .NET API V2 Service](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/18538/translation-manager-using-net-api-v2-service)