# Tridion 9.1 During Component Save, send to translation using Event handler

Tags: event-system, translation-manager, sites-9.1

I have a business requirement whenever the user saves a Component, it should send automatically to Translation Job using Event Handler. Does any one have an idea or already implemented this business logic?
Waiting for your valuable solution.

Comment: What's the setup (what are the moving parts) - and I'd suggest you don't just refer to the tags you've applied?
What have you tried - why didn't that seem to work? What have you read - no point in people spending their time advising links you've already read - as noted above? > Waiting for your valuable solution. Many people will have done this and as you state, there's value in a solution. I doubt people are just going to start pasting in generic solutions without more detail from yourself. Looking forward to helping when you've updated with more information https://stackoverflow.com/help/how

Comment: Sending something automatically for translation on a save event sounds to me like a really great way to give money to SDL. Often content is not ready to be sent for translation when it's saved the first time, and many other times it may be just a small edit that you don't necessarily want to translate (adding a comma, changing the order of some bullets, etc). Translation Manager and editorial governance on this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the documentation link for more details

https://docs.sdl.com/816112/691717/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5/triggering-translations-from-event-system

Hope it helps !

Comment: Anand - Already referred and not helpful for me. thanks for reply

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why it wasn't helpful? Did you take a look at or have tried the examples and ran into some issue along the way?

Answer (score -1):

I agree with @Nuno comments. It's not a good idea but technically it's doable.

Let me give you some ideas and references to start with. Using this below Component Save event you may need to call Translation Manager API to create the new job to add items to send for translation dynamically, you might need to identify the target Publication Uris also here it might be needed for creating a translation job.

```
EventSystem.Subscribe<Component,SaveEventArgs>(HandlerForCommitted, EventPhases.TransactionCommitted);
```

Event Handler example refers to the [SDL documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/783502/100551/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/event-handler-example).

To download the [Translation Manager API reference documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/783502/691586/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/api-reference-documentation-downloads), download [API reference documentation downloads](https://docs.sdl.com/binary/783502/745699/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/sdl-tridion-sites-translation-manager-api).

Here are the translation manager reference DLLs you might be needed for Translation API.

- Tridion.TranslationManager.V2.Data.dll
- Tridion.TranslationManager.V2.TmService.Client.dll

> SessionAwareTmServiceClient _client = new
> SessionAwareTmServiceClient();

Refer to this answer for [Translation SOAP Service netTcpBinding and endpoint](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/18525/binding-details-for-translation-manager-using-net-api-v2-service-from-external). similarly, you will need to adjust based on your TM service version.

**Note:**

@Anand shared in his answer Translation Manager Event system examples reference useful in case if you want to hook the translation job. not for creating a new translation job.

I hope it helps.